# netdb.h: No such file or directory while trying to run a socket program (in C language) on windows

Tags: c, sockets, networking, compiler-errors, winsock

I have the following C code and I'm required to run it. but I always have the following Error in the used libraries. I tried downloading the MinGW and I added its path to the Environmental variables, but still same problem.

> [Error] netdb.h: No such file or directory

I'm trying to run my code on Windows. It is a C language Socket program.
The libraries are:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr
```

Another question, If I want to run a socket on my laptop as a client and a server (windows), how do I do so?

Comment: Take a look at [How Do a ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because your question as posed is unlikely to get much attention.  It appears you've done little or no work on your own to solve your problem.

Comment: @JJF Well, I was given this code by my professor, I searched the whole internet on how to run it, but I keep getting the same error over and over again... netdb.h: No such file or directory

Comment: See https://handsonnetworkprogramming.com/articles/differences-windows-winsock-linux-unix-bsd-sockets-compatibility/.

Answer (score 3):

I do the same stuff at these moment.
I had the problem too. If you run the script on windows, you have to install the right header files. I do it with...

```
#ifdef _WIN32
//For Windows
int betriebssystem = 1;
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <ws2def.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int betriebssystem = 2;
#endif
```

Try to run it. Maybe you have to link the libary for "ws2_32".

Comment: I tried doing almost as what you wrote me, but I ended up with some error in the code that says "undefined reference to 'bzero' " I tried swapping it to memset( ), but I still received few more errors, something like: ```undefined reference to `socket@12'```
or ```undefined reference to `htonl@4'```

Comment: And those are the libraries that I used
```#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")```

Comment: I guess these headers are platform specific. Like `winsock2.h` is windows-only header file.