# #include <netdb.h> in clion (with C) and working with threads

Tags: c, clion

I'm trying to include: #include <netdb.h> in clion with c.
This not recognize the include, what I should to do?
I am new in clion, I used to work with visual studio.

Moreover, how I should work with threads in clion?
There is something I should do?

Comment: Does Windows have a `hetdb.h`? I don't think so... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206157/netdb-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-trying-to-run-a-socket-program-in-c-la

Answer (score 1):

You need a different set of headers for Windows. You need your code to adjust for the difference:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32)
/* Windows headers */
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <sysinfoapi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#else /* or check here for unix / linux & fail if OS unrecognized */
/* POSIX headers */
#include <netdb.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#endif /* _WIN32 */

/* shared headers */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Of course, you might not need all the headers I listed, or you might need others, so adjust the code to your needs.

Also, if header inclusion ordering is a non-issue on your system, you can move shared headers outside the `if/else` block.